# Métodos Executando em Paralelo

Tags: java

Oi.

Acho que essa vai ser uma resposta bem simples, mas é algo que eu ainda tenho dúvidas de como fazer.

Digamos que eu tenha, uma classe `PedidosListener` responsável por fazer a leitura de um arquivo .csv e armazenar as informações desse arquivo em uma variável local. E uma classe `PedidosController` responsável por pegar as informações da variável contida em `PedidosListener` e fazer o processamento dos valores a partir daí.

A minha dúvida é, como fazer a classe `PedidosListener` ficar lendo o arquivo .csv de forma contínua, e quando ele perceber alguma mudança no arquivo, adicionar a mudança para a variável local e mandar a informação de que houve mudança de volta para a classe `PedidosController` sem que isso pare a execução da `PedidosListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listener geralmente é um tipo de interface implementada por classes de objetos que respondem a certas ações. Se você tem uma interface OnFileContentChangedListener, por exemplo, ela declarará um método chamado OnFileContentChanged. Quem quiser responder aos eventos de mudança de arquivo deve ser de uma classe que implementa essa interface. Mas isso provavelmente não vai ser suficiente. É preciso registrar esses objetos como ouvintes do evento com o objeto que percebe que tal evento ocorreu. Um exemplo, no caso do Android, é quando você faz botao.setOnClickListener(seuListener), onde seuListener é um exemplar de uma classe que implementa OnClickListener. O que vai acontecer é que o botão, ao receber do gerenciador de interface com o usuário um sinal de que houve um clique nele, ele vai buscar em sua lista interna de listeners interessados em saber que houve um clique e chamar o método OnClick de cada um deles.

Como você pode ver, não existe mágica: alguém tem que chamar seu método. No caso do OnFileContentChangedListener, vai ter que existir um objeto que registra listeners de mudança de arquivo. Esse objeto vai ter que ter alguma forma de saber quando houve uma mudança no arquivo pra chamar os métodos OnFileContentChanged dos listeners registrados. Isso pode ou não ser feito por polling (ficar o tempo todo indo lá e verificando a data de modificação, por exemplo). Mesmo que seja, ainda é muito melhor do que cada objeto interessado ficar fazendo seu próprio polling. No mundo real, muitos eventos desse tipo funcionam através de sinais, pois polling não é muito eficiente.

Em resumo: seu listener não vai ficar parado esperando. Ele vai registrar-se como ouvinte e seguir com a vida. Quem vai ficar responsável por avisar quando a hora chegar é o "observador". Sobre como implementar um observador de arquivos, verifique as implementações da interface WatchService (Java 7). Se precisar de mais informações, adiciono quando estiver no PC.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode começar a trabalhar com threads. Existem duas formas de criar uma thread, a primeira é criar uma classe extendendo de threads, a segunda é criar uma classe implementando Runnable, ambas as formas funcionam e ambas as formas você  simplesmente implementa o método run () com sua lógica e invoca o método start() da sua thread.  Existe um tutorial bem completo no site da caelum http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/programacao-concorrente-e-threads/#17-1-threads

Se tiver alguma dúvida posta ai que vamos te ajudar